# React & Typescript component props type for `Component`

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following HOC in React:

```
`restricted` prop
    const ConditionalSwitch = ({component: Component, showIfTrue, ...rest}) => (

    showIfTrue
        ? <Component {...rest}/>
        : null
);
```

How do I define the props so that Typescript will be happy with it?

`{component: Component, showIfTrue, ...rest}`

I tried

```
export interface CSProps {
    component: any,
    showIfTrue: boolean
}
```

How do I handle the `...rest` here?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, in typescript if you want to denote that your component doesn't need to have all the properties you can use `Partial`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve type safety, you need to make `ConditionalSwitch` generic and have it infer the full props passed to the component based on the actual value of `Component`. This will ensure that the client of `ConditionalSwitch` will pass in all the required properties of the used component. To do this we use the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049871/how-do-i-type-this-as-jsx-attribute-in-typescript):

```
const ConditionalSwitch = <C extends React.ComponentType<any>>({ Component,  showIfTrue, ...rest}: { Component: C, showIfTrue: boolean} & React.ComponentProps<C> ) => (
    showIfTrue
        ? <Component {...(rest as any) }/>
        : null
);

function TestComp({ title, text}: {title: string, text: string}) {
    return null!;
}

let e = <ConditionalSwitch Component={TestComp} showIfTrue={true} title="aa" text="aa" />  // title and text are checked
```

When passing the `rest` to the component we do need to use a type assertion because typescript is not able to figure out that `{ Component: C, showIfTrue: boolean} & React.ComponentProps<C>` minus `Component` and `showIfTrue` is just `React.ComponentProps<C>` but you can't have it all :)

Comment: I get `the left hand side of an arithmetic operation must be...` on the `? <Component {...(rest as any)}` line

Comment: @mikeb works for me. What version of ts are you using ?

Comment: Typescript is 3.3.3333

Comment: @mikeb https://github.com/dragomirtitian/so-answers/tree/so-55004765 I tried on 3.3.1 and 3.4 (don't have 3.3.3333 right now)

Comment: I restarted Intellij and now I get `Cannot find name Component` right after the `?` - it's like it does not see that it is an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export interface CSProps {
    component: any;
    showIfTrue: boolean;
    [key: string]: any;
}
```