# ReactTS extend type by dynamic Component Props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

Is it possible to have a React component what can find out dynamically what props its got?

Example:

```
type BaseType = {
   baseProp?: ...
   as?: ...
}

type Extended = {
   extendedProp?: ...
}

<Base /> // expected props => { baseProp }
<Base as={ExtendedComponent} extendedProp={...} /> // expected props => { baseProp, extendedProp }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a cue from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049871/how-do-i-type-this-as-jsx-attribute-in-typescript) answer we can, using intersections first infer the type of the props from `as` and then use those props to validate any extra properties:

```
type BaseType = {
  baseProp?: number
}

type Extended = {
  extendedProp?: string
}

declare const ExtendedComponent: React.FC<Extended>
function Base<T = {}>(p: BaseType & { as? : React.ComponentType<T>} & T): React.ReactElement{
  if(p.as) {
    const Child = p.as;
    return <div>{p.baseProp}<Child {...p as T}></Child></div>
  }else {
    return <div>{p.baseProp}</div>
  }
}


let s = <Base /> // expected props => { baseProp }
let a = <Base as={ExtendedComponent} extendedProp="a" />
```

Comment: Wow... been trying to achieve this for hours... :D. Thought there is a solution as this can be handled in compile time. Thanks alot!