# Default generic on dynamic component (ReactTS)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

My question is kinda to my previous one: [ReactTS extend type by dynamic Component Props?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56237212/reactts-extend-type-by-dynamic-component-props/56237368#56237368)

So lets say I've got the next lines:

```
type Base = {
    baseProp: ...
}

type Extend = {
    extendProp: ...
}

// use this if "as" undefined
type DefaultPropsToExtend = {
    defaultToExtendProp: ...
}

declare const ExtendedComponent: React.FC<Extend>
declare const DefaultExtendedComponent: React.FC<DefaultPropsToExtend>

function Base<T = DefaultPropsToExtend>(props: BaseProps & { as: React.ComponentType<T> } & T): React.ReactElement {
    const Wrapper = props.as
    return <Wrapper />
}
```

So what I expect when I call the next lines are:

```
<Base /> // props can be => { baseProp, defaultToExtendProp }

What props actually I am seeing => { baseProp }

If I am doing the next then things working property, but this way I need to be explicit about the default "as" every time.
<Base as={DefaultToExtendComponent} /> // => { baseProp, defaultToExtendProp }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best option is to use overloads. One overload can be generic and accept any component. The other overload can have the default:

```
type BaseProps = {
    baseProp: string
}

type Extend = {
    extendProp: number
}

// use this if "as" undefined
type DefaultPropsToExtend = {
    defaultToExtendProp: number
}

declare const ExtendedComponent: React.FC<Extend>
declare const DefaultExtendedComponent: React.FC<DefaultPropsToExtend>

function Base(props: BaseProps & DefaultPropsToExtend): React.ReactElement
function Base<T>(props: BaseProps & { as: React.ComponentType<T> } & T): React.ReactElement
function Base<T = DefaultPropsToExtend>(props: BaseProps & { as?: React.ComponentType<T> } & T): React.ReactElement {
    const Wrapper = props.as || (DefaultExtendedComponent as unknown as React.ComponentType<T>)
    return <Wrapper {...props as T}/>
}

let a = <Base baseProp="" defaultToExtendProp={0} />
let a2 = <Base as={DefaultExtendedComponent} defaultToExtendProp={0} baseProp="" />
```

Comment: Man, you are an absolute saviour! As I am kinda new to TS I did not know I could do this (even if I would know, most likely wouldn't come up with this lol)

Thanks once again!!