# React + Typescript: dynamic class based on a Prop

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a component where I'm passing a prop called `HtmlTag` and, base on its value, I would like to extend the Prop Interface with the correct props base on the html tag.

I've tried creating a Type that acts as a map and then try to extend it, e.g.

```
type AllAttrs = {
  a: AnchorHTMLAttributes,
  button: ButtonHTMLAttributes
}
```

and trying the following for now

```
interface Props extends AllAttrs["a"] {
  sanitize?: string;
}
```

and I get "an interface can only extend other interfaces"

This is how I use my component:

```
<Element
   Component="a"
   ... more props
>Test</Element>
```

The goal is to have TS complaining about missing props, like href, if it isn't passed

Answer (score 1):

You can have an interface that extends a indexed type query, but you need to put it into a separate type alias (it can't directly be in the `extends` clause).

However that is not the right approach here. Using an intersection type in the props will allow the inference to work as expected (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049871/how-do-i-type-this-as-jsx-attribute-in-typescript)):

```
type AllAttrs = {
  a: AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>,
  button: ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>
}


function Element<T extends keyof AllAttrs>({ Component, ...rest}: { Component: T} & AllAttrs[T]){
  return <Component {...rest as any} ></Component>
}

let r = <Element
  Component="a"
  href=""
>Test</Element>

//Error href not on button
let r2 = <Element 
  Component="button"
  href=""
>Test</Element>
```

Comment: awesome! it works very well. I didn't know that I can use `&`, I was trying to extend and I was getting an error.

Comment: The only thing that doesn't work right now is the `children` prop, when I pass it I get: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'HTMLCollection | (HTMLCollection & string) | (HTMLCollection & number) | (HTMLCollection & false) | (HTMLCollection & true) | (HTMLCollection & ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<...>) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>) | (HTMLCollection & ReactNodeArray) | (HTMLCollection & ReactPortal)'`

Comment: nvm, I was providing an invalid interface for the `span` attribute, all good, thank you!