# Dynamic props depending on other prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, typescript-generics

I have this component, which is just a title and an icon on the right, and the container of this component can be a button, an anchor element, or a Link element from `react-router-dom`.

[image: component]

I was able to create the container dynamically like so:

```js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
// ....
type Props = {
  as: "button" | "a" | "Link";
  title: string;
  icon: string;
};
const ActionItem: React.FC<Props> = ({ as, title, icon }: Props) => {
  const Container = styled(as === "Link" ? Link : as)`
    display: flex;
    // ...
  `;

  return (
    <Container>
      {title}
      <div style={{ flex: 1 }} />
      {icon}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

But now what I'm trying to accomplish is to have dynamic props depending on the `as` prop, so, for example, if the `as` prop is equal to `Link` show all the props for the Link component like `to`, `replace`, etc. Or if the `as` is equal to `a`, show all the props for the anchor element like `href`, `target`, etc.

```js
<ActionItem 
  as="Link"
  to="/profile"
  ...
/>
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56500173/react-typescript-dynamic-class-based-on-a-prop) but it didn't work, mostly because in the example they are using native HTML elements, and I need to use those (button and anchor element) plus the Link component.

I don't know if what I'm trying to find is possible or if it is another possible solution for this?

BTW, [here's a code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-pascal-m8d1b) with the code

Edit:
Here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-leaf-l4pb4) of the code working as it should

Comment: For sake of curiosity, I want to know how do you got that sketching effect on the boxes?

Comment: I use excalidraw, it's an online tool for drawing

Comment: Actually, I wanted to implement the same effect as excalidraw, but I didn't want to dig into their source code (how they do it in canvas), so I guess you've implemented that with a package or something :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use a so-called [discriminating union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) (or discriminative union). Let's use the `as` prop as the discriminator.

You already have

```
type Props = {
    as: "button" | "a" | "link"
}
```

Break that out to

```
type Props = 
    { as: "button" } | 
    { as: "a" } | 
    { as: "Link" }
```

Now simply add to each part of the union what props you expect there for Typescript to deduce what other properties are possible, given the discriminator prop `as`:

```
type Props = 
    { as: "button" } & ButtonProps | 
    { as: "a" } & AProps |
    { as: "Link" } & LinkProps
```

Done!

By the way, I used made up names for the complementary props you need, you have to look up the names of the types you want to intersect your discriminator prop with yourself.

Comment: can i do it by interface?