# How to add defaultProps to a generic functional component with component injection in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a functional component `Button` that takes a prop `as` to inject an HTML element or another component. I want to default the `as` prop to the `Link` component of `react-router`. This would make `Link`'s `to` prop a mandatory prop of `Button`. So, I should get an error when writing `<Button>Press me!</Button>`, but there is no error reported by the compiler.

I'm on typescript v3.5.3 with the following settings in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

Here is my current situation (simplified) with `Link` as default for the `as` es6 style:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

interface ButtonProps {
  children?: string
}

type ElementInjector<T extends React.ElementType> = {
  as: T
} & React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>

export const Button = <T extends React.ElementType>({
  as: Tag = Link,
  ...props
}: ButtonProps & ElementInjector<T>) => {
  return <Tag {...props} />
}
```

So given the above, this is the result and the expectations:

```js
<Button>Button</Button>            // error   - asking for `as` not `to`
<Button as={Link}>Button</Button>  // error   - ok
<Button to="/">Button</Button>     // error   - asking for `as`
<Button as="a">Button</Button>     // success - ok
```

How do I get the first one to fail?

Also it would be cool to solve the following ones too. Not related to `defaultProps` but to the generic approach.

```js
<Button as="a" to="/">Button</Button>      // success - error expected
<Button<'a'> as="a" to="/">Button</Button> // error   - ok
```

---

[Example to play with](https://codesandbox.io/s/generic-fc-defaults-kwd53?fontsize=14&view=editor)

Answer (score 2):

The parameter default will not be taken into account when inferring the type parameters to the component. Since there is no other place to take `T` from it will default to `unknown`. The solution would be to add a default type for `T`

```
export const Button = <T extends React.ElementType = typeof Link>({
    tag: Tag = Link,
    ...props
  }: ButtonProps & ElementInjector<T>) => {
    return <Tag {...props} />
  }

let x = <Button>Button</Button>                      // error expected
let x1 = <Button tag={Link}>Button</Button>          // error   - ok
let x2 = <Button to="/">Button</Button>              // success - ok
let x3 = <Button tag="a">Button</Button>             // success - ok
```

About your second problem, it's similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049871/how-do-i-type-this-as-jsx-attribute-in-typescript) question but I have't been able to get it to work, will post if I have an update.

Comment: Thank you very much Titian! Unfortunately I get different results. Maybe it is easier to share here: https://codesandbox.io/s/generic-fc-defaults-kwd53?fontsize=14