# Correct type to set for a renderAs Propery in Typescript React Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Components sometimes need to be able to render as a different HTML element, depending on its context. For example, this `Card` component.

```js
import React from 'react';

export type Props = {
    className?: string,
    renderAs: any
}

export const Card: React.FC<Props> = function Card({ renderAs, className, children }) {
    const Element = renderAs;
    return (
        <Element className={`card  ${ className ? className:'' }`}>
            { children }
        </Element>
    )
}
```

When actually using the component, all works as it is supposed to:

```js
<Card renderAs="section">...</Card>
<Card renderAs="div">...</Card>
```

But I am not sure, if using `renderAs: any` is the correct type, for this use case and I would appreciate some insight on this!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049871/how-do-i-type-this-as-jsx-attribute-in-typescript)

Comment: I think it does, but I am afraid I am not experienced enough to apply it to my situation. If I read this correctly, I have to add a new type myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual type you are passing is `React.ElementType`, leaving

```
export type Props = {
    className?: string,
    renderAs: React.ElementType
}
```

What you say by this is that you want to enable `renderAs` to be set to some intrinsic JSX element such as `section`, `div`, `span` ...

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with how I am using it. Maybe when you define it like that you have to use it differently than how I described it?

Comment: I made a simple implementation here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-mfrh2. Note that I took for granted that `CartCard` was a typo that infact should be `Card`. Was that incorrect of me?

Comment: Thank you! It was all working correclty, I just got errors before, but now it works all correctly, thanks :)